# Alert $scope.data dynamically in ionic and angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a for loop that aids in creating dynamic template for popup alert in ionic.
I would like to alert the user input tagged with the dynamic model name.

The name of the ng-model is formed dynamically in this manner "`ng-model="data.serialNo' + i + '`".

And I attempt to alert the input by using the following manner:

```
 var serialInput = '$scope.data.serialNo' + i;
 alert(serialInput);
```

The above code return me the string "$scope.data.serialNo1" instead of the value of the ng-model serialNo1.

How should I go about getting the model value dynamically?

```
var templatePt2 = "";
 for (i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
            templatePt2 += '<div class="item row row-item min-705" ng-model="details.item_id"><div class="col col-centre col-sep col-13 item-text-wrap">' + i + '</div><div class="col col-centre col-sep col-90 item-text-wrap"><input type="text" placeholder="Serial No." ng-model="data.serialNo' + i + '"></div></div>';
        }

        var templatePt1 = '<ion-scroll zooming="true" direction="y" style="width: 100%; height: 160px;"><div style="height: 80%">';
        var templatePt3 = '</div></ion-scroll>';

        var teamplateForm = templatePt1 + templatePt2 + templatePt3;

        var myPopup = $ionicPopup.show({
            template: teamplateForm,
            title: 'Item Id: ' + item_id,
            subTitle: 'Please enter unique serial number',
            scope: $scope,
            buttons: [
            { text: 'Cancel' },
            {
                text: '<b>Save</b>',
                type: 'button-positive',
                onTap: function (e) {
                    for (i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
                        var serialInput = '$scope.data.serialNo' + i;
                        alert(serialInput);
                    }

                }
            }
        ]
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
var serialInput = $scope.data['serialNo'+ i];
alert(serialInput);
```